# MediaPlayer. Muted phone - muted application.

Tags: android

How to set user phone audio settings to MediPlayer? For example when my phone is in mute mode my app should be muted too.

Comment: Which kind of "Mute mode" do you mean? Android is able to "mute" any of the 3 main audio streams (System, Media and Alarm). What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: System audio stream I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only have to make sure which stream your App is using to play Audio.

For example if you are Playing Audio on the System stream, the System mute will apply.

Use

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
```

to set your MediaPlayer to play on the System stream.

Thinking further you could also mean the notification stream. Select it using:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

See the Android [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer) documentation page for more info.